# Cloudera Kerberos authentication error using CeleryExecutor Airflow

Tags: celery, airflow, kerberos, cloudera

Please help as I am a little clueless..

I am trying to upgrade our Airflow installation including Kerberos authentication from the localexecutor to the celeryexecutor. Currently, we run the airflow installation from only one server.

The exact same sqoop job fails using the celeryexecutor due to an kerberos authentication error while the localexecutor is successful:

```
Client cannot authenticate via:[TOKEN, KERBEROS]; Host Details : local host is: "lsrv****.linux.****/10.251.128.148"; destination host is: "lsrv***.linux.****":8020; , while invoking ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over lsrv****.linux.****/10.251.128.104:8020 after 1 failover attempts. Trying to failover after sleeping for 1377ms.'
```

kerberos settings:

```
[kerberos]
ccache = /tmp/krb5cc_32606

# gets augmented with fqdn
principal = airflow
reinit_frequency = 3600
kinit_path = kinit
keytab = /var/lib/airhome/.certs/airflow.keytab
```

Is there anything that needs to change in the kerberos or celery setup to have kerberos work in combination with celery executor? Or does anything need to change in the Cloudera Hadoop settings? (e.g.: `hadoop.security.token.service.use_ip`?)

Does it have to do something with the additional ip adress mentioned in the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run also `airflow kerberos` where you run `airflow worker`. It's Kerberos ticket renewer component in Airflow.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html#kerberos

Comment: Well yes, I know that and the ticket renewer is running perfectly fine. However, there is some difference in kerberos authentication between local vs celeryexecutor as I get the authentication error..

Comment: Actually, I'm using Kerberos authentication with Celery Executor smoothly and my Kerberos configurations in airflow.cfg are same as you. How many worker nodes do you have? Did you run ´airflow kerberos´ in all of them?

Comment: Currently, we are trying out this setup with one server only, so this will be one worker node with 16 workers setup I guess. Can you help me with 'running airflow kerberos in all of them'? As we have just one airflow kerberos service running for the 16 workers. Would really appreciate your help

Comment: It is very strange to me that just changing the executor to LocalExecutor makes the kerberos authentication work again.